# Symfony form validation errors are displayed twice

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I need a simple form for the registration of a user. The form validation works as expected, except for the fact that the validation errors coming from a callback-constraint are shown twice for some reason.

I inserted a random number in an error message to see if the callback was called once or twice. The 2 error messages show the same random number, so the calback is (probably) only called once.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Extra question: "All the errors from the callback function are shown on the same place in the form (as expected) . Is it ( easily ) possible to specify the field at which a validation error should be dislayed? "

The form type class looks as follows :

```
class RegisterType extends AbstractType{

static private $em;
static private $translator;

public function __construct( EntityManager $em , TranslatorInterface $translator){
    RegisterType::$em = $em;
    RegisterType::$translator = $translator;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder , array $options){
    $builder
    ->add('email','email',[
            'attr'=>['placeholder'=>RegisterType::$translator->trans('your.email')],
            'label'=>false ,
            'constraints'=>[new NotBlank() , new Assert\Email()]])
            ->add('password','password',[
                    'attr'=>['placeholder'=>RegisterType::$translator->trans('your.password')],
                    'label'=>false ,
                    'constraints'=>[new NotBlank()]])
                    ->add('confirmPassword','password',[
                            'attr'=>['placeholder'=>RegisterType::$translator->trans('confirm.password')],
                            'label'=>false ,
                            'constraints'=>[new NotBlank()]]);
}

public function getName(){
    return 'register';
}

public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'constraints' =>array( new Assert\Callback( array('AppBundle\Forms\Type\RegisterType','validateForm' )  )),
    ));
}

static public function validateForm(array $data, ExecutionContextInterface $context){
    if($data['email']){
        $user = RegisterType::$em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findByEmail($data['email']);
        if($user){
            $context->buildViolation('email.is.used'.rand())->addViolation();
        }
    }

    if($data['password'] && $data['confirmPassword']){
        if($data['password'] != $data['confirmPassword']){
            $context->buildViolation('password.confirm.failed')->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

The form is called in a controller as follows:

```
        public function registerFormAction(Request $request){

        $form = $this->createForm('register');
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()){
            //TODO
        }

        return new JsonResponse(['success'=>false,
                                 'message'=>$this->renderView('AppBundle:Security:register.html.twig' , ['form'=>$form->createView()])
        ]);

    }
```

The twig template used to render the form is :

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{%- block form_row -%}
    <div class = "form-group">
        {{- form_errors(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form) -}}
    </div>
{%- endblock form_row -%}
{{ form(form) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the {% form_theme form _self %} functionality can only be used if your template extends another template.

[image]

So i put the form_row block in another file and i used 
{% form_theme form "otherfile.htmltwig"%}
Which worked fine.

Comment: Actually, extending 'base.html.twig' works as well and is more elegant

Answer (score 6):

You are displaying the form errors and form widgets twice!

You have

```
<div class = "form-group">
    {{- form_errors(form) -}}  //displays all form errors
    {{- form_widget(form) -}}  //displays all form widgets (not the labels!)
</div>
```

and

```
{{ form(form) }}  //displays the whole form
```

in your code.

Why don't you just render the form by yourself, then you can also set where the form errors should be shown.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_errors(form.username) }}  //errors for the "username" field of your form
        {{ form_label(form.username) }}   //labels for the "username" field of your form
        {{ form_widget(form.username) }}  //formfields for the "username" field of your form
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Also, there's a twig function called `form_rest(form)` which will display all form fields that aren't manuelly rendered yet!

Comment: mmm, my intent was to override the form_row() function with the form_row block to show only the error and the widget and not the label.

Comment: Then take away the `form_label()`, you mustn't render it if you don't want. But it's much easiert to do it this way then to manipulate the functions provided. Basically it's just one more row of code each.

Comment: Doing as you suggest works, but it would invove writing each field of the form twice. Which is what i am trying to avoid using the form customization.

Comment: By the way, the widgets are only displayed once.

Comment: `form_rest(form)` great tip